# having problems with the while loop in C

Tags: c

this code  is not workin for some reason. i tried doing the while loop with stdbool.h lib but that doesn't work. can someone tell me where am i wrong?. i was just trying to make a rock paper game in c in which the right the the rules for winning and when the user has not won i declare it that he has lost. its probably something with loop

````c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void win(){
    printf("You win!\n");
}
int main(){
    int i =1;
    int var=1;
    char machine_choice[3];
    char ask='\0';
    //things that can happen 
    machine_choice[0]="rock";
    machine_choice[1]="paper";
    machine_choice[2]="scissor";
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int machine = rand() % 3; //machines actuall choice
    char choice[50];
    while (i=1) {     
        printf("what is ur choice. write it in lowercase pls.\n");
        scanf("%s", choice);
        printf("%s\n", choice);
        printf("%s\n", machine_choice[machine]);
        if (choice==(machine_choice[machine]))
        {
            printf("its a tie!\n");
            var++;
        }
        if (choice=="paper" && machine==0)
        {
            win();
            var++;
        }
        if (choice=="scissor" && machine==1)
        {
            win();
            var++;
        }
        if (choice=="scissor" && machine==1)
        {
            win();
            var++;
        }
        if (var==1)
        {
            printf("do u want to play again(y/n)\n");
            scanf(" %c", &ask);
            if (ask=='n')
            {
                printf("okayy!");
                break;
            }    
            else
            {
                var=1;
            }
            
        }    
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: ```char machine_choice[3];```, that's only for single character, e.g., `'D'`, `'T'`, `'A'`, you need to write something like `const char *machine_choice[3];`

Comment: That's not how string(`char array`) are comparred in `C`, use `strcmp()` function from `string.h` header file.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the variable `i`? Beside of that, the condition in your loop is not a comparison (`i == 1`) but an assignment (`i = 1`). The latter returns always "true" as it is non-zero. -- Anyway, learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)... And raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum, it should have warned you about several problems.

Comment: Don't skip the simple exercises just because you want to make something functional. If you want to use `while` loops, first understand them doing exercises, and only *then* proceed to what you want to make.

Comment: thanks!, seems to working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `while (i=1)` the i always remains equal to 1 so it will never exit that loop, even if you entered an assignment with `i = 1` and not a condition. If you wanted to enter a condition you had to enter `while(i==1)`.